# Wrapping multiple implementations in Go

Tags: go, struct, interface, dry, embedding

I have an application that has multiple concurrent implementations of the same API (e.g. one backed by a SQL database and another by a dataset stored in an XML file). What I'd really like to do is to define a parent type for each type of thing in the API that

1. holds the member variables that are common to all of the implementations and
2. defines the methods that all implementations must have.

So, in (invalid) Go, I want to do something like:

```
type Person interface {
    Name string
    Title string
    Position string
    Boss() *Person
}

type Person_XML struct {
    Person
}

func (p *Person_XML) Boss() (*Person, error) {
    // Poke around an XML document and answer the question
    return boss, nil
}

type Person_SQL {
    Person
}

func (p *Person_SQL) Boss() (*Person, error) {
    // Do a DB query and construct the record for the boss
    return boss, nil
}
```

But, of course, that's not legal since only structs have member variables and only interfaces have member functions. I could do this with just interfaces like this:

```
type Person interface {
    Name() string
    Title() string
    Position() string
    Boss() Person
}

type Person_XML struct {
    NameValue string
    TitleValue string
    PositionValue string
    Person
}

func (p *Person_XML) Name() string {
    return p.NameValue
}

func (p *Person_XML) Title() string {
    return p.TitleValue
}

func (p *Person_XML) Position() string {
    return p.PositionValue
}

func (p *Person_XML) Boss() (Person, error) {
    // Poke around an XML document and answer the question
    return boss, nil
}
```

and similarly for other implementations. Is there an alternative that doesn't force me to turn member variables into member functions? What's best practice for such a use case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best practice would be to provide an interface:

```
type Person interface {
    PersonName() string
    PersonTitle() string
    PersonPosition() string
    Boss() (Person, error)
}
```

And also provide a struct which contains the common fields *and* the methods to get them:

```
type BasePerson struct {
    Name     string
    Title    string
    Position string
}

func (p *BasePerson) PersonName() string     { return p.Name }
func (p *BasePerson) PersonTitle() string    { return p.Title }
func (p *BasePerson) PersonPosition() string { return p.Position }
```

(Note: `*BasePerson` itself does not implement `Person` as it doesn't have a `Boss()` method.)

Any type that embeds `*BasePerson` will automatically have its methods *promoted*, and so to implement `Person`, only the `Boss()` method will need to be added.

For example:

```
type PersonXML struct {
    *BasePerson
}

func (p *PersonXML) Boss() (Person, error) {
    // Poke around an XML document and answer the question
    var boss *PersonXML
    return boss, nil
}
```

`*PersonXML` does implement `Person`.

Example using it:

```
var p Person
p = &PersonXML{
    BasePerson: &BasePerson{
        Name:     "Bob",
        Title:    "sysadmin",
        Position: "leader",
    },
}
fmt.Println(p.PersonName())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hVrmbcDOyij)):

```
Bob
```

To create the `PersonSQL` type, you again only have to add the `Boss()` method if you embed `*BasePerson`:

```
type PersonSQL struct {
    *BasePerson
}

func (p *PersonSQL) Boss() (Person, error) {
    // Do a DB query and construct the record for the boss
    var boss *PersonSQL
    return boss, nil
}
```

`*PersonSQL` again does implement `Person`.

Comment: Aha: Embedding.  That's the term for the use of `*BasePerson` in `PersonSQL` and `PersonXML` that makes this example as concise as it is.  New go golang, I was unaware of this feature.  Excellent post answering exactly my question.

Answer (score 0):

We can apply first approach since struct can embed interface along with fields. If you look at package [sort](https://golang.org/src/sort/sort.go) It uses same approach in which it embeds an interface inside an struct.

```
type Interface interface {
    // Len is the number of elements in the collection.
    Len() int
    // Less reports whether the element with
    // index i should sort before the element with index j.
    Less(i, j int) bool
    // Swap swaps the elements with indexes i and j.
    Swap(i, j int)
}

type reverse struct {
    // This embedded Interface permits Reverse to use the methods of
    // another Interface implementation.
    Interface
}
```

So doing your approach is absolutely valid. And you can implement interface easily using struct receiver.

```
// Less returns the opposite of the embedded implementation's Less method.
func (r reverse) Less(i, j int) bool {
        return r.Interface.Less(j, i)
}
```